# Salary Table for Candidate and Job

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two SQL tables, Candidates and Jobs:

```
create table dbo.Candidate ( 
  Id int not null constraint primary key clustered (Id),
  Name nvarchar (200) not null
)

create table dbo.Job ( 
  Id int not null constraint primary key clustered (Id),
  Name nvarchar (200) not null
)
```

I need to include in both tables a SalaryValue, a SalaryPeriod(Month, Year, ...) and a SalaryCurrency (EUR, USD, etc) ...

I am considering using three more tables as follows:

```
create table dbo.Salary ( 
  Id int not null constraint primary key clustered (Id),
  CurrencyId int not null,
  TimePeriodId int not null,
  Value decimal (10, 2) not null
)

create table dbo.Currency ( 
  Id int not null constraint primary key clustered (Id),
  Name nvarchar (20) not null,
  Code nvarchar (4) not null
)

create table dbo.TimePeriod ( 
  Id int not null constraint primary key clustered (Id),
  Name nvarchar (20) not null
)
```

What do you think about this scheme?

And what would be the best way to relate Salary with Candidate and Salary with Job?

Comment: Should this not be on the CodeReview SE site, maybe even the DBA SE site since that one is has 'Data Modelling and database-design, including referential-integrity' in it's "What to ask" section, since it is not a specific problem, more a design question?

Comment: @marc_s I just added the tag: MSSQL Server

Comment: There is not enough information about your business rules to supply a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Currency.Symbol --> rename to Currency.CurrencyCode or just Code and most probably it is CHAR(3).

Candidate --> Normally it is good idea to split the name into FirstName and LastName (maybe MidName also).

I would also say that salary can be changed. Then you need to put StartDate and EndDate of the salary.

Comment: And how would you relate Salary table to Candidate and Job tables? Add a SalaryId FK in Candidate table and SalaryId FK in job table? I think this might be the best approach

Comment: I would create 1 more linked table, but you can also have Current salary and job in the candidate table.

Answer (score 0):

**Salary**

Depending on the salary structure of the company, it may make sense to use an extra salary table with referring ids as you got it right now. Expecially bigger companies use job levels and salary ranges, so if this is an issues for you, consider adding additional columns to your salary table to describe them like `JobLevel` and/or `Salary Range`. Remember that these information might be for internal use only.

**Candidate**

I would not create a relation to the salary table directly, since the candidate salary expecations will most likely vary a lot. You should consider adding a `CurrencyID`, `TimePeriodID` and a `Salary`.

**Job**

If you decide it makes sense to use an extra table for Salary as discussed above, just create a relation to the table with the `SalaryID`.